# Given the snippet below how can I confirm the type of v[0] parsing the <vector> header file in VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, header-files

Given the code below how can I confirm that the type of `v[0]` is `const int&`, going through the  header file?

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> v(1);
    decltype(v[0]) b = 1;
}
```

As an example, that's what I was trying to do in VS2010:

1. With the mouse over `vector` above, I clicked with the mouse right button and selected `Go to definition` and I found

   ```
   template<class _Ty, class _Ax = allocator<_Ty> >
   class vector
       : public _Vector_val<_Ty, _Ax>
   {}
   ```
2. I then searched for `operator[]` and found `const_reference operator[](size_type _Pos) const`
3. Again with the mouse over `const-reference` I clicked with the mouse right button and selected `Go to definition` and found `typedef typename _Alloc::const_reference const_reference;`.

I don't know where to go from this point on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really shouldn't use the implementation to acquire information like this. The chain of typedefs can be quite long. Instead refer to either the language standard or [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/) which reflects the information in the standard. In the case of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) a `const_reference` is defined to be reference to a constant of type `value_type` which is a type `T` (or `_Ty` for the MS implementation).

*.*Prior to C++11 it was declared as a reference to a constant of type `Allocator::reference`*

Answer (score 0):

Use  [type_traits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/) and static_assert. std::is_same can directly tell you if it's const int& or not. For other cases you may use is_reference or other queries. static_assert is evaluated by intellisense, so you can even get the result without compile.